# Revoke a permission from one user

Tags: sharepoint-online

I will demonstrate my situation with a simple exemple; I have 2 libraries and a group of users with edit permission.

- For the first library, the permissions won't change.
- For the second library, I want to keep the edit permission on for all members, except one member who should only read files from this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can restrict a few users or a single user to read the documents in the library by managing unique permission for your library as the following:

1. Go to your library > **Library Settings**.
2. Click on **Permissions for this document library**
3. Open the Group where user has edit permission.
4. Select user and From the above Ribbon, > Click on **Remove User Permissions**. So now user should have none permission to the document library.
5. From the above Ribbon, > Click on **Stop the inheritance**.
6. Then click to **Grant Permission** to provide a unique permission for specific user.
7. Provide the required user/users and select **Read** Permission Level

I hope this helps.